# Why is Window.Show() still stealing focus?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, c#-4.0

I have a Mahapps MetroWindow (WPF) that is minimized to the task tray sometimes and a task that runs every minute with a loading form. My problem is when the app is minimized it steals the focus when the loading form is activated using Show(). Even when I set ShowActivated and Topmost to false. I've tried setting these in the XAML as well.

How can I show this new loader window (in case the user restores the app from the task tray) without it stealing focus and restoring itself from a minimized state?

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        this.IsEnabled                      = false;
        LoaderForm loaderForm               = new LoaderForm();
        loaderForm.Owner                    = Window.GetWindow(this);
        loaderForm.ShowActivated            = false;
        loaderForm.Topmost                  = false;
        loaderForm.WindowStartupLocation    = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
        loaderForm.Show();
    });
})
```

Comment: Focus, activation and foreground are distinct window states.  You are setting the Owner property, the window is therefore always ahead in the Z-order of the *this* window.  So if your current window is in the foreground then this new window is always visible and always covers it.  Setting its IsEnabled property just makes it very awkward for the user to continue interacting with your UI.  Very unclear what you are *really* trying to accomplish.

Comment: `Dispatcher.Invoke`(alone) inside a new task makes no sense for me. Why not just execute the code in the current thread(assuming it's main thread) or throw away that `StartNew` ?